# Sizing of and Type of Power-loss / Brown-Out Protection Capacitor

Tags: power, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, low-power, supercapacitor

I found a few resources and this question here: [power-loss protection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4579/help-with-power-loss-protection-using-capacitor)

I'm using an [MCP16301](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005004D.pdf) step down regulator to turn 12v to 3.3v

I'm having trouble determining I in this equation:
C=I×t/ΔV

with a minimum of 6v input I get this

- ΔV = 12v-6v = 6v
- t = 5seconds
- I = ?

**Question 1:** 
If my output current is 1A max, and assuming 90% efficiency, does that mean the input current is 1A/.9 = 1.11A?

**Question 2:**
What's the correct type of capacitor for this application?

**Question 3:**
How do you actually detect the power loss? I'm aware than I can use an interrupt to handle the event, but what's the correct circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcCMh5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 0.5F at 12V is going to be tough to source you may want to reconsider some of the design criteria to reduce this. Getting the MCU to immediately drop high current loads at brownout is a good option as is reducing the amount of time that it has to continue running.

Comment: I could probably drop it to 2-3 seconds

Comment: At that 3 1F 5V supercaps in series should do the trick.

Comment: How much current are you actually trying to pull while in backup mode?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can hook up an ammeter to the 12v input into regulator and reply back. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: @GisMofx -- that would help, yes...

Answer (score 1):

Q1 No input current for a dc/dc convertor = 1A/.9 x Vout/Vin = 0.30525A this will increase as input voltage drops to 1A/.9 x 3.3/6 =0.6105A for the next bit use an average of 0.5A this gives a bit of margin as well.

Q2 Your cap C=I*t/dV

```
 dV is your brownout detect point say 11V-6V=5V

 t =5s (do you really need this long)

 I= 0.5A

 C=0.5F
```

This is in the supercap class go to farnell or one of the other suppliers and find the cap there.

Q3  You use a comparator one input is a divided down version of the cap voltage say 1/10 = 1.2V nominally. The other input is a stable reference (zener+resistor?) set at 1/10 your brownout detect voltage=1.1V. Make sure the comparator output is compatible with your mcu in. You may be able to find a 3.3 V supply voltage comparator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, capacitors are a bad choice for the sort of thing you're talking about. At 1 farad (and that's a farad, not a microfarad), your equation suggests that you will lose 1 volt/second for a 1 amp current.

And yes, a 90% efficient regulator will need an input of 1/0.9, or 1.11 tines the output current.

You're getting confused about your diagram because it's not quite correct. It should look something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6x2T5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And you'll note that the power loss detector will not work when the energy storage device (shown as a capacitor) is dead. That's true. But it has to be powered by something, and obviously can't  be powered by the external power source.

Comment: If a cap is not the best choice, what should be used instead? In your circuit, my load would be the regulator, correct? Also, it's seems like sourcing a 12v+ 1F-ish cap is expensive. Maybe I'm searching for the the wrong thing?

Comment: It depends entirely on a) how much current you're drawing, b) how much voltage you can afford to lose, and c) how long a duration you need to cover. If it's milliseconds, then a cap may be OK. If it's seconds, a supercap might do. If it's minutes to hours, a battery might serve. If it's days, you might need a backup generator. There's no way to tell without knowing details. For instance, backup for a clock which only draws a mA or less might use a battery and last for years.